# Locking gas cap for 2013 Fit?

Tags: honda, fuel-cap

I asked at the dealer, and they don't have a locking gas cap as an OEM accessory.  Is there a recommended one that has maximum likelihood of compatibility with a 2013 Fit?

As for how to install it, my current plan is to ask the dealer (which has a shop) if they would do it.  Failing that, their is a private shop that I will turn to.

The suggested option should be orderable from Canada.  If it has a tether, so much the better, but that's secondary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many aftermarket locking gas caps that will work for you. No need to have the dealer install its easy enough to simply remove your old one and turn this one on.

Here is an example that is said to fit a 2013 Honda Fit.
https://www.autozone.com/emission-control-and-exhaust/fuel-cap/duralast-fuel-cap-5991/4399_0_22759

Comment: That's very helpful. They let you enter in your car model and then display whether the cap fits. Silly me, I did not say that I'm in Canada. I checked amazon.ca, which also lets you specify your car: https://www.amazon.ca/Gates-31780-Fuel-Tank-Cap/dp/B000C2WF0E/ref=au_as_r?Make=Honda|59&Model=Fit|2855&Year=2013|2013. But I don't trust this because it isn't clear whether the claim to fit is from Amazon or Gates. I posted the question of fit on the product page of amazon.ca and amazon.com, and also sent it to Gates.

Comment: BTW, the reason I was thinking that I needed to have an expert do the replacement is because my non-locking OEM gas cap is tethered. YouTube says that you can yank the tether from its anchor on the gas cap door, so that may be a non-issue. It'd be better if the replacement after market locking gas cap also has a tether, but from web search so far, locking and tethering seem to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: The tether is usually just clipped in. Not much to worry about. The good thing about ebay or amazon is if it doesn't fit you can return it.

Comment: I never knew that.  Thanks!  I will have to take a closer look at the tether.  My readings thus far indicate that a special ridge is needed on the cap.